# Good pratice on componentize Widgets in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm buiding a simple app with Dart/Flutter. I tried to apply some concepts (such as 'components') from other frameworks and ended up with a question regards what is consider good pratice in cases like this.

This is my Home so far:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_recognition_poc/components/layout/app_bar.dart';
import 'package:image_recognition_poc/components/layout/drawer.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal[100],
        appBar: DefaultAppBar().build(context),
        drawer: DefaultDrawer().build(context),
        body: Container());
  }
}
```

and this is one of my widgets:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DefaultAppBar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      title: Text(
        'Portal parceiro',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.teal[600],
      elevation: 0,
    );
  }
}
```

As the Scaffold.appBar field only accepts an `PreferredSizeWidget` which implements the class `Widget` I built my DefaultAppBar object as shown `DefaultAppBar().build(context)`.

It works, but I would like to know if this is good pratice or if would be a better way to active this componentization.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to pass the context to the build function, that a framework job.
And your app bar should implement the PreferredSizeWidget.

```
@override
 Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);
```

Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64325495/10795937